# Powershell script to fill out Start in section with path

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Trying to get powershell to fill out the "Start in" section within the shortcut file via:

```
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory
```

Script so far:

```
$file = pwd
# Create a Shortcut with Windows PowerShell
$TargetFile = "$file\file.vbs"
$ShortcutFile = "$file\file.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = $file
```

This is the error i receive.

```
Exception setting "WorkingDirectory": Cannot convert the "C:\PATH\TO\FOLDER" value of type "PathInfo" to type "string".
At line:8 char:5
+     $Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = $file
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
    $Shortcut.Save()
```

Help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Use `$file = $pwd.Path` or `$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = $file.Path`. `$pwd` returns a `PathInfo` object with many properties. The `Path` property contains the path string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pwd` is an alias for command [Get-Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-location?view=powershell-6). It returns a `PathInfo` object with many properties that points to the current directory. The `Path` property contains the path string.

Therefore, you need to access that `Path` property from the `pwd` output or from `$file`:

```
$file = (pwd).Path
$TargetFile = "$file\file.vbs"
$ShortcutFile = "$file\file.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = $file
```

---

The automatic variable `$pwd` also contains the `PathInfo` object with many properties that points to the current directory. You can access the same value using `$pwd.Path`:

```
$file = $pwd.Path
```

---

**Additional Info:**

You can view properties and type information using the [Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-6) command:

```
$pwd | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PathInfo

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method     type GetType()
ToString     Method     string ToString()
Drive        Property   System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo Drive {get;}
Path         Property   string Path {get;}
Provider     Property   System.Management.Automation.ProviderInfo Provider {get;}
ProviderPath Property   string ProviderPath {get;}
```

Each property value can be accessed directly using the member access operator `.` with the syntax `object.Property`. The `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property` syntax is also a popular way to retrieve a property value.

```
# Member Access Method
$pwd.Path
C:\MyCurrentPath

# Select-Object Method

$pwd | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
C:\MyCurrentPath
```

---

`PathInfo` objects contain a `ToString()` override method that returns the path as a string.

```
$pwd.ToString()
C:\MyCurrentPath

(pwd).ToString()
C:\MyCurrentPath
```